# Drywall thin crack above door repair

Tags: patching-drywall

I want to repair this thin line crack above my "laundry closet" door. I was just going to mix some mud, but I wasn't sure if I need to break this line in, use tape, etc. I've only ever tried small holes.

I am concerned just filling may result in a new crack as the house changes seasons, etc.

The door also has one of those ball clasps (not directly in line) which I am going to switch out, but thought maybe that was adding to the issues and might need to also account for that.

[image: photo of thin crack in drywall above the door.]

Comment: Are you planning on repainting that wall in the future(year or two)?  patching probably want to tape also and is easy, but matching paint colour is the hard part.  I would probably just patch now and put a picture/poster over it for now till repainting comes near.

Comment: The house is relatively new, I still have the original paint and know the exact paint to get if the old paint is no good.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you carve the crack out so the new mud has a place to grab onto and is a more substantial amount that will be less prone to cracking. If you mud over that crack it will return within a a year. It looks like it has a sliding door so it won't be as abused as if it was a swinging closing door.

Mesh tape can help. I've done it with and without mesh successfully. The wider you go with your mud, the more it will blend in and the less chance it will crack in the future.

Comment: I would use paper tape over mesh for this, it will resist cracking better. I have seen mesh split right along a crack line with too much movement.

Comment: > looks like it has a sliding door so it won't be as abused
These are swing out doors, they used to be attached will a ball grip, I removed that and will be switching to magnets if that makes a difference.  I have a bag of easy sand 45 that I researched for some holes I want to fill, is this also the right filler for this job?

Comment: also, procedurally ? - (1) carve out the crack (2) fill with joint compound (3) tape (4) more joint compound (5) sand smooth (6) paint ?

Answer (score 0):

Carve out the crack as RocketmanZ suggested, and buy some flexible spackeling.
It is made for cracks from slight movement and the crack will not show up again in a year as others said.
I have also used latex caulk in cracks like this with good success.